# how to line break if the equation not fits in the width?

Tags: css, mathml

I have a MathML script which shows an equation and its usage, in which I want's a max of 600 PX width.

```
<span style="color: red;max-width: 600px;">
    <math>
    <mn>2</mn>
    <mfenced>
    <mrow><mi>l</mi><mi>b</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mi>h</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>h</mi><mi>l</mi></mrow>
    </mfenced>
    <mo>=</mo>
    <mn>2</mn><mo mathvariant="sans-serif">x</mo><mfenced>
    <mrow><mn>26</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo mathvariant="sans-serif">x</mo><mn>32</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>+</mo><mn>28</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo mathvariant="sans-serif">x</mo><mn>58</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>+</mo><mn>69</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo mathvariant="sans-serif">x</mo><mn>98</mn><mtext>cm</mtext></mrow>
    </mfenced>
    </math>
</span>
```

and i wan't to break the line into new line from the '=' sign if it not fits in 600PX.
and also needed that broken piece at the right side
thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
<mo linebreak="goodbreak" indentalign="right">=</mo>
```

to make the equal sign a preferred breakpoint, with right-alignment of the second line.  But whether this works will depend on the features of the MathML renderer you are using (not all renderers implement the linebreaking features of MathML3).  It should work with MathJax, but not in Firefox's native MathML rendering.

Note, however, that formula indentation only applies to block-level math; i.e., you would need to use `<math display="block">` in order for the right-alignment to occur.

Also note that `max-width` only applies to block-level elements, so it will have no effect on a `<span>`.  You would need to use something like a `<div>` instead.

You also should use the proper symbol for the "times" rather than an "x".  E.g.,

```
<mo>&#xD7;</mo>
```

should do it.  This will get the spacing right as well as give the proper semantics for multiplication.

Comment: me using mathjax(to work MathML code in chrome)
is this what u mean?
`<div style="color: red;max-width: 600px;">
            <math display="block">
            <mn>2</mn>
            <mfenced>
            <mrow><mi>l</mi><mi>b</mi><mo></mrow>
            </mfenced>
            <mo linebreak="goodbreak" intentalign="right">=</mo>
            <mn>2</mn><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mfenced>
            <mrow><mn>26</mn><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mn>32</mn></mrow>
            </mfenced>
            </math>
        </div>`
(removed some code because not fits in comment)
Its not working for me.
please help

Comment: Yes, that is the correct code.  But note that automatic linebreaking is OFF by default in MathJax, so you need to enable it in your configuration.  See [the documentation](http://www.mathjax.org/docs/2.0/output.html#automatic-linebreaking) for details.

Comment: BTW, the expression you give is not 600px wide when I view it, so no break is needed, so it shows as one line.  You may need a longer expression in order to see the effect you desire.

Comment: i z me removed some code to fit in the comment box.
me done the fixes and line break works now.
but the alignment not works for me.
if I give display block, the whole equation comes to center.
and intentalign="right" too not works.

Comment: here is the code.
`<math display="block"><mn>2</mn><mfenced><mrow><mi>l</mi><mi>b</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>b</mi><mi>h</mi><mo>+</mo><mi>h</mi><mi>l</mi></mrow></mfenced><mo linebreak="goodbreak" intentalign="right">=</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mfenced><mrow><mn>36</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mn>26</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>+</mo><mn>26</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mn>16</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>+</mo><mn>16</mn><mtext>cm</mtext><mo>&#xD7;</mo><mn>36</mn><mtext>cm</mtext></mrow></mfenced></math>`

Comment: OOPS! I had a typo.  It is `indentalign` not `intentalign` (I have fixed it in my answer above).  That should take care of the indenting of the second line.  The first is centered since that is MathJax's default for displayed equations.  You can override that using `<math display="block" indentalign="left">` or perhaps you want `<math display="block" indentalignfirst="left" indentalign="right">` in which case you don't need to specify `indentalign` on the `<mo>` itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `max-width` property is ignored for inline elements. You need to set `display: block` on the `span` element (or, more logically, use `div` or `p` instead of `span`) to enforce a maximum width.

If you wish to allow a line break after the equals sign only, you need extra markup. Then you can set `white-space: nowrap` on any element inside which a break is to be disallowed. Alternatively, you can use no-break spaces if there are no other characters that allow line breaks after them.

I think you should also get the mathematical notations right if you use MathML; specifically, the letter “x” is not a multiplication symbol, and the correct symbols “×” and “⋅” require spaces around them. This is relevant to the topic because when you use spaces, you need to consider whether they are breaking or non-breaking.

Comment: i am using mathjax to view the MathML code in chrome also.
I think that mathjax overrides this change.
its not working for me.
please help